# Increase numerical stability of a computation

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, stability-theory, condition-number

Let $A$ be a $N\times N$ symmetric positive definite real matrix, and $f$ a column vector of length $N$.  Moreover, let's call $C$ the inverse of $A$ and $\alpha$ the vector of solution of the linear system
$$
A\alpha=f.
$$

I am interested in computing, for each $k\in\{1,2,\dots,N\}$, the value
$$
E_k:= {\alpha_k \over C^{(k)}_k},
$$
where $\alpha_k$ is the $k$-th element of $\alpha$, and $C^{(k)}_k$ is the $k$-th element of the $k$-th column of $C$ (that is, the $k$-th element of the diagonal of $C$).

I know that the matrix $A$ is badly conditioned, therefore the computation of $E_k$ using the above formula is not stable, because it require to invert the matrix~$A$.  Is there a formula to compute the same value which is more stable from a computational point of view?

Comment: I am afraid it cannot be done better, than using matrix inverse. The best what can be done is to compute the Cholesky decomposition of A using complete pivoting, and then compute the inverse.

Comment: I'm not sure that it can be done, but it's not clear to me that it can't.